# sysctlbyname for kern.osrelease returns NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

Here is my code and I am trying to get OSVersion here on IOS devices. And that warning is at line return ret; ----> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'char' from a function with result type 'char *'; take the address with &. When I change ret to &ret it still doesn't work.

```
char *getOSVersion() {
        char str[256];
        size_t size = sizeof(str);
        char ret = sysctlbyname("kern.osrelease", str, &size, NULL, 0);
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sysctlbyname returns integer value and you try to return locally created char pointer from your function. I think you should either take your char pointer as a parameter and assign it in function body or you should return char by value. 
Try using in this way;

```
char getOSVersion() {
    char str[256];
    size_t size = sizeof(str);
    char ret = (char)sysctlbyname("kern.osrelease", str, &size, NULL, 0);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted you are returning the result of the sysctl call (error code) instead of the actual string returned by it.

Probably you meant `return str;` in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

- your code:

```c
char *getOSVersion() {
    char str[256];
    size_t size = sizeof(str);
    char ret = sysctlbyname("kern.osrelease", str, &size, NULL, 0);
    return ret;
}
```

- Analysis

  - `char *getOSVersion() {` is your `function definition` -> means return value type is `char *`
  - but your implementation `return ret;` means return type is `char`
  - so: `char *` != `char`
- Soluton

according to your code, seems you want to return `os version string`

and the `os version` value returned by `sysctlbyname` is stored inside `str`

so you need change `return ret;` to `return str;`

- Updated code could be:

```c
char *getOSVersion() {
    char osVersonStrBuffer[256];
    size_t size = sizeof(str);
    int retErrorNumber = sysctlbyname("kern.osrelease", osVersonStrBuffer, &size, NULL, 0);
    return storeReturnValueStr;
}
```

- Related doc: (apple's sysctlbyname)[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1387446-sysctlbyname]